# SMTPAuthenticationError at /

Tags: python-3.x, django, smtp, google-email-settings-api

my django app is not being able to send email. On my email less secure apps is turned on and i have unlocked captcha. am stuck i dont know what am missing. any help will be appreciated.

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.9
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'shield_sec']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/apple/projects/Django/ingabo_sec/shield_sec/views.py", line 17, in contact
    send_mail (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 69, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError at /
Exception Value: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l188sm1732224lfd.127 - gsmtp')
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
] 

# Email settings 
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
#EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect ,Http404
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings 
from . forms import ContacForm

# Create your views here.

def contact (request):  
    if request.method == "POST":
        sender_name = request.POST.get('sender-name',False)
        sender_number = request.POST.get('sender-number',False) 
        sender_email = request.POST.get('sender-email',False)
        sender_subject = request.POST.get('sender-subject',False)
        message = request.POST.get('message',False)

        send_mail (
            sender_name, 
            sender_number,
            sender_email,
            ['***********@gmail.com'],
            sender_subject,
            message,
            )

        return render (request,'shield_sec/contact.html', {'sender_name': sender_name}) 
    else:
        return render (request,'shield_sec/contact.html', {})
```

I suspecting probably there problem might lie in my settings.py but everything looks fine.

Comment: ``EMAIL_USE_SSL = False`` ?

Comment: hello yes i commented it out since i was using port 587. if i set both to true definitely it fires an error . Thank you